# Не подключаются стили CSS в проекте на Django

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django

Всем добрый день! При разработке проекта на Django не удается подключить стили CSS. Создана директория static, где лежат как стили, так и картинки. Картинки отлично отображаются, но стили CSS не применяются. Все сделала, как написано в документации.

Файл form.html:

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="slylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/index.css" %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image">
           <img class="img2" src="{% static "image/comp.png" %}"/>
        </div>
        <h2>
            <span>Текст</span>
        </h2>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Файл index.css

```css
h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 5em;
 color: rgb(255, 140, 0);
}
```

Файл settings.py

```js
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'formdummy.apps.FormdummyConfig',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Файл urls.py в директории formdummy:

```js
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.FormDummyView.as_view())
]
```

Файл urls.py в директории sibur_os:

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('form/', include('formdummy.urls'))
]
```

Расположение файлов в директории:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: urls покажите...

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 добавила в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

`rel="stylesheet"` вместо `rel="slylesheet"`

Comment: К сожалению, все равно не получается. Причем файлы не подключаются только через тег <link>, а через <script> все ок (картинки и js).

Comment: У Вас еще опечатка в коде, надо rel="stylesheet"

Comment: Эти вложенные кавычки не имеют никакого значения, потому что всё равно исчезают после работы шаблонизатора.